# Single thread per channel model with netty OIO

Tags: netty

Does a single thread per channel model with Netty OIO mean that either write or read operation
can be executed on a single channel at a time? 
I am writing distributed applications with a small number of connections (~20) and I was thinking of using Netty OIO. However, it is very important for me not to be blocked on receiving messages on some channel while corresponding worker thread is blocked with writing? 
Is there a way to achieve this with Netty OIO, i.e., can I have one thread for writing on a channel and one thread for reading on the same channel?

Comment: Old Question / Updated Info: Just want to note that OIO is depreciated since 4.1 and will be removed in future versions of netty. [OIO Netty.IO API Docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/oio/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

In OIO a write will never get blocked by a read. So you can write stuff to the Channel while it waits for data to receive.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean a write to the *channel* is not being blocked, but a write to the connection is? Because with auto-read set to true, I can see that my writes are not happening until I read something first (which is a feature I don't fully understand either, because as a client, why would I start with a read?).