# Single thread per channel netty OIO

Tags: netty

Related question: [Single thread per channel model with netty OIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494578/single-thread-per-channel-model-with-netty-oio)

I've written an **OIO** client-server using **netty**, where I send a number of messages from server to client (and vice--versa) after the connection is up.

As far as I can tell, it looks like writes to channel block reads from channel.

Is that normal behaviour for netty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Netty's OIO transport performs read and write in the same thread.  Therefore, while you write, the read for the channel which is being written is blocked.